# angular send image and json object to php service

Tags: php, angularjs

i need to send image file and json object from my angular app to php service. this is what i have tried

```
 fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('file', file);
 fd.append('payment', ss);
 console.log(file)
 $http({
     url: url + "duosoftware.payment.service/payment/saveImage",
     method: "POST",
     headers: {
         "securityToken": "123",
         'Content-Type': undefined
     },
     data: fd,
     transformRequest: angular.identity
 }).then(function(response) {

 }, function(response) {

 })


var_dump($_FILES["file"]);
```

in here i only send the image only. how can i append my json object to this request and access from my service. this is the object

```
 var ss = {
                "name" : "www"
            }
```

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, use an existing library like [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: did you tried var_dump($_POST["payment"]);

Comment: Yeah but it says payment undefined